# PostgreSQL with asyncpg return a prefix string for a json_agg() select

Tags: python, json, postgresql, asyncpg

I'm trying to use a `json_agg()` function of PostgreSQL with python and asyncpg. The data returned is a `list` of just one element that begins with `<Record jsonb_agg=` string and than a correct json.

I'd like to have the json string directly from the DB and not use the "workaround" in the code. Is something wrong in my code?

```py
"""Example PostgreSQL JSON with asyncpg"""

import asyncio
import json
import asyncpg
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

DSN = "postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1/testdb"
QUERY = 'select jsonb_agg(t) from (select * from "tmp") t;'


async def fetch_data_from_db():
    """get data from DB."""
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(DSN)
    result = await conn.fetch(QUERY)
    await conn.close()
    return result


async def get_list():
    """Get List"""
    result = await fetch_data_from_db()
    return result


class Person(BaseModel):
    """Person model."""
    id: int
    name: str
    surname: str

    @classmethod
    def parse_from_json(cls, json_data):
        """Parse from json."""
        try:
            return cls(**json.loads(json_data))
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Error: {str(e)}")


async def main():
    result_raw = await get_list()
    ### this is a workaround ###
    element = result_raw[0]
    json_string = element["jsonb_agg"]
    json_result = json.loads(json_string)
    ############################

    print(f"type and len of result_raw: {type(result_raw)}/{len(result_raw)}")
    print(f"type and len of json_result: {type(json_result)}/{len(json_result)}")
    try:
        persona_data = json_result[0]
        persona = Person(**persona_data)
        print("Valid JSON object:", persona)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

```
type and len of result_raw: <class 'list'>/1
type and len of json_result: <class 'list'>/3
Valid JSON object: id=8 name='Donald' surname='Duck'
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."tmp" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL,
    "name" character varying NOT NULL,
    "surname" character varying NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "tmp_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

INSERT INTO "tmp" ("id", "name", "surname") VALUES
(8, 'Donald',   'Duck'),
(9, 'Daisy',    'Duck'),
(10,    'Scrooge',  'McDuck');

select * from tmp;
 id |  name   | surname 
----+---------+---------
  8 | Donald  | Duck
  9 | Daisy   | Duck
 10 | Scrooge | McDuck
(3 righe)
```

I expect a json valid string in `result_raw`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs [here](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#example-automatic-json-conversion), you can tell asyncpg to deserialise the JSONB automatically. You would need your `fetch_data_from_db` function to look like this:

```py
async def fetch_data_from_db():
    """get data from DB."""
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(DSN)
    await conn.set_type_codec(
        'jsonb',
        encoder=json.dumps,
        decoder=json.loads,
        schema='pg_catalog'
    )
    result = await conn.fetch(QUERY)
    await conn.close()
    return result
```

With this change, the contents of `result_raw[0]['jsonb_agg']` is a list of dicts rather than a JSON string.

Comment: so If I understood correctly, your solution "moves" the `json.loads` from my code to the native code of asyncpg. But why the string `<Record jsonb_agg=` is returned.
also because I don't have any string like that from the command line.

Comment: `<Record jsonb_agg...` appears to the the `repr` of the asyncpg object that wraps the returned row from the db.

Comment: Setting this up on each connection might be annoying, but I would suspect you can do it automatically when creating a [connection pool](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#connection-pools), using the `setup` argument (but I haven't tried this).

Comment: Ok, I understood better with more examples I did. 

Regards